# List up-coming events from my Calendar in Office 365

Tags: outlook, calendar, sharepoint-online

This is the scenario:

1. I'm in my corporate intranet Sharepoint Site in the home page.
2. I want to see the up-coming events from my Outlook calendar.

The big question is: if I already logged in my Office 365 account, I need a special authentication/authorization for show this data using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can create calls using Outlook Calendar [REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations), and then for the authentication/authorization you can have a middleware hosted SharePoint APP which hanldes all your security constraints before calling these APIs.